# How can I bind the values of the parameter in the SQL statement using Perl?

Tags: perl, sqlite

HI am using SQLite DB and whenever I try to bind the values of parameter into the statement I am getting an error.

Here's the piece of code:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UserId,UserName,CardNo,GroupId,Role,VerifyType FROM
    UsersList limit ?,? "); 
$sth->bind_param(1, undef,SQL_VARCHAR);
$sth->bind_param(2, undef,SQL_VARCHAR);
$sth->execute($page,$results_per_page);
```

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: datatype mismatch at line 68.
```

Can anybody Please help me out and let me know what datatype am I supposed to put in place of SQL_VARCHAR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using `bind_param()` wrong. Take a look at this example:

```
use DBI qw(:sql_types);  # Don't forget this

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    SELECT bar FROM foo GROUP BY bar HAVING count(*) > ?;
});
$sth->bind_param(1, 5, SQL_INTEGER);
$sth->execute();
```

i.e.: no arguments to `execute()` and the value goes in the `bind_param()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Limits are integers and not text, so I'd guess `SQL_INTEGER` might be a thing to try first?

Comment: I TRIED using SQL_INTEGER Also but the same error exists,i even used use DBI qw(:sql_types); but nothing is working ;-(

Answer (score 0):

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO table 
                       (name, age)
           VALUES 
                       ('$name', ?);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

#if not $age insert NULL value 
$sth->execute($age ? $age : undef);
```